# On Facebook Like button click update database by +1?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Is it possible to update the database counter when a person clicks on a like button.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

Would an ONclick event or a Jquery/ Ajax script work for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this documentation, specifically the edge.create event

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/